# Cannot open database "dbname" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user "machinname\username"

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to run a console application written in C# using visual studio 2010
in which i am accessing a temp database of Microsoft Sql Server Managment Studio.

But the application gives exception as follows:

```
"Cannot open database "dbname" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user `machinname\username""
```

And my connection string is as follows:

```
con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=temp;Integrated Security=True";
```

Why might this fail with such an error?

Comment: "Please help ASAP" - Please check your tone. No one here is obligated to help you.

Comment: it seems your db uses SQL authentication...

Answer (score 6):

The user that the application is running under (probably you since this is a console application), does not have login permissions on the database.

`Integrated Security=True` indicates that Windows Authentication is being used - either use a user that has appropriate permissions on the database, or grant the appropriate permissions to the user.

Comment: How do i grant the permission to the user?

Comment: @user693730 - You need administrator rights on the database. Use Sql Server Management Studio - under the management area you can add users, logins and set the right access permissions.

Comment: As i am new to the Sql Server Management Studio i am not able to find management area

Answer (score 1):

If you change the connection string to have a sql server username and password that can be associated with the database then it will work if the application is not running under a windows identity that is not associated with sql server windows authentication

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=temp;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=<username>;Password=<pw>"
```

the application is running under a user that is not recognised in sql server

Comment: 'Proper' meaning a Sql login. :)

Comment: well yeah to be strictly correct then yes an actual sql server login lol

Comment: My oint was simply that Sql has two modes of authentication, none being more or less proper than the other. :)

Comment: It has new exception as " Login failed for user 'username'."

Comment: the username and password that you add in the connection needs to be a valid sql server user login that also has the correct execution rights on the database

Comment: The log in Details are valid even though i am not able to logged in

Comment: The error is very much specific to login credentials. Either the username and password are not correct or database server is rejecting the connection because there are no permissions for user to login.