# Why attaching database programmatically using C# fails?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server and C#. I have `Computer1`, Windows 7. I use Windows Forms and SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

I developed a software which will be running later in other Windows computers and those computers will only have SQL Server database engine (no management studio installed).

Instead of attaching the database manually I want to attach it programmatically when the programs starts.

I created a folder `(D:\MyFolder)` and I placed the `mydb.mdf` and `mydb.ldf` files in it (re-created database).

Then I used the following code to attach `mydb` database to the server and it was successful done and I can read from the database. I have to give `MyFolder` Full control permission or otherwise the program will throws database login failure.

Also I have `Computer2` which has exactly same windows, same SQL Server version as in `computer1`. I copied both `mdf` and `ldf` files from `computer1` and pasted them in `D:\MyFolder` in `computer2` and I run the program the database attached successfully.

Until now everything works fine and both computers attached the database fine.
Now I go to `computer2`, to `D:\MyFolder` and right click on the database files and delete them and I go to `computer1` and copy the database files and paste them into `computer2` (in same directory `D:\MyFolder`) and when i run the program it says:

> Cannot open database "mydb" requested by login. the login failed. Login failed for user 'Computer name/ username'

Even after I gave permission for everyone on `MyFolder`, it still throws the same error.

I searched all day and I checked these answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212318/cannot-open-database-mydb-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-fail),  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878990/cannot-open-database-login-failed-for-user), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558192/cannot-open-database-dbname-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-fa), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164306/fixed-cannot-open-database-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37163090/login-failed-for-user-and-cannot-open-database-database1-mdf-requested-by-t) but nothing helped. Anyone knows what can I do to fix it? any suggestion will be helpful.

```
private void Attach_DB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // This is to give permissions to folder
        string folderPath = @"D:\MyFolder";
        var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
        var directorySecurity = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
        var currentUserIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        var fileSystemRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(currentUserIdentity.Name, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow);

        directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(fileSystemRule);
        directoryInfo.SetAccessControl(directorySecurity);

        // This is to connect to the attached database
        SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost ; AttachDbFilename=D:\MyFolder\mydb.mdf; Initial Catalog =mydb; Integrated Security=true");

        SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand();
        DataTable DataTable = new DataTable();

        SqlDataAdapter Sql_Data_Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable.Rows.Clear();

        MyConnection.Open();
        MyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table_Customers ";
        MyCommand.Connection = MyConnection;

        Sql_Data_Adapter.SelectCommand = MyCommand;
        Sql_Data_Adapter.Fill(DataTable);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = DataTable;

        MyCommand.Parameters.Clear();
        Sql_Data_Adapter.Dispose();
        MyConnection.Close();
    }
    catch (System.Exception excep)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(excep.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are other ways to do a backup and a restore.

Comment: How can you do anything manually in C#? It's a programming language so everything must be programmatic.

Comment: Enigmativity- it can be done via MS SQL management studio but I do not want to.

Comment: @Toni - Don't forget to use the `@` notification system when replying to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Server's instance name in connection string.

e.g.

if your are using Express Edition and your instance name is SQLEXPRESS, then try `localhost\SQLEXPRESS` or `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` instead of just `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in your connection.

```
Integrated Security=true
```

According to the documentation,

> When true, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.

The Windows account credentials rarely work from one computer to another. If you cannot use a DDL (the preferred way) then you need to use Username and Password in your database before exporting the file.

Comment: ok but Before adding a User you must first create a global Login, under Security -> Logins.you can add them as a User under a particular database. but I do not want to create global user on each machine that the program will be installed in. any other idea?

Comment: I thought you said you were using the Express version. You don't need to create a user in each machine.